# AppEngine TaskQueue Logging Levels

Tags: google-app-engine, logging, task-queue

I have an application that is using push task queues,
I would like to know some info about what parameters are being sent to the tasks in the admin console.

I figured an easy solution would be to do a log.*info* to give me the information, these don't seem to show up in the admin console though.

Only *warning*, *severe* level logs show up. So my current solution it so write these info logs out as warnings (which is terrible).

I see lots of examples of people using log.info in task queues.
Am I supposed to see *info* level logs in the admin console?
Am I looking in the wrong place?
Is there a way to turn on info level logging in the admin console?

Thanks,
Nathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on the language you are using, but GAE comes with a default logging level of WARNING (at least in Java it does) so anything being logged below that level wont go through to the logs.

If you are using Java you need to edit your `WEB-INF/logging.properties` file and change the value from

> .level = WARNING

to

> **.level = INFO**